# SQL select from list where white space has been added to end

Tags: sql, oracle, select, whitespace

I'm trying to select some rows from an Oracle database like so:

```
select * from water_level where bore_id in ('85570', '112205','6011','SP068253');
```

This used to work fine but a recent update has meant that `bore_id` in `water_level` has had a bunch of whitespace added to the end for each row. So instead of `'6011'` it is now `'6011       '`. The number of space characters added to the end varies from 5 to 11.

Is there a way to edit my query to capture the `bore_id` in my list, taking account that trialling whitespace should be ignored?

I tried:

```
select * from water_level where bore_id in ('85570%', '112205%','6011%','SP068253%');
```

which returns more rows than I want, and

```
select * from water_level where bore_id in ('85570\s*', '112205\s*','6011\s*', 'SP068253\s*');
```

which didn't return anything?

Thanks
JP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should `RTRIM` the `WHERE` clause

```
select * from water_level where RTRIM(bore_id) in ('85570', '112205','6011');
```

To add to that, `RTRIM` has an overload which you can pass a second parameter of what to trim, so if the trailing characters weren't spaces, you could remove them. For example if the data looked like 85570xxx, you could use:

```
select * from water_level where RTRIM(bore_id, 'x') IN ('85570','112205', '6011');
```

Comment: Thanks Tom, however I should have specified in my post that some bore_id are strings not integers, like 'SP068253'. I will edit now to fix.

Comment: Thanks, I've modified the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `replace` function to remove the spaces

`select * from water_level where replace(bore_id, ' ', '')  in ('85570', '112205', '6011', 'SP068253');`

Although, a better option would be to remove the spaces from the data if they are not supposed to be there or create a view.

Comment: Thanks Jimmie, this seems to work, will accept the answer. I assume this will only work with space and not tab or newline? And yes I agree the better option would be to fix up the data but they admin guy is away and I need the data now.... you know, the usual story :)

Comment: You can pass whatever you like into the replace function and it will remove it. @Tom's answer is better though, RTRIM will remove all whitespace characters including tab and newline and should be more performant than a replace

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing `bore_id` is VARCHAR or VARCHAR2.  If it were CHAR, Oracle would use (SQL-standard) [blank-padded comparison semantics](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements002.htm#BABJJGBI), which regards `'foo'` and `'foo     '` as equivalent.

So, another approach is to force comparison as CHARs:

```
SELECT *
  FROM water_level
 WHERE CAST(bore_id AS CHAR(16)) IN ('85570', '112205', '6011', 'SP068253');
```